# Create a base36 key in MySQL and Oracle on insert

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a requirement that the unique key for a table is a base36 value of the current timestamp in milliseconds.

So i know i can do this on the java side, to create the key and insert then retry if it fails to be unique or something like that.  But what I really want to do is see if MySQL and Oracle can do that for me.

I know i can create unique keys with sequences, but I'm not sure if there is some way to do this as well.

I'd like to know how to do it in MySQL and Oracle if possible, it's still not determined which DB we will use for the project...

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on the table, and in that trigger, do something like `SET NEW.id = CONV(NOW(), 10, 36);`

Note however that if you have more than one insert per second, you'll get duplicate ids.

To use time up to milliseconds, you need at least MySQL 5.6 and then use `SET NEW.id = CONV(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP * 1000, 10, 36);`

Comment: so if two inserts are in the same millisecond it would throw a duplicate key error and I would have to just retry the insert I assume?

Comment: Well, yes, if two insert happen on the same millisecond, one would throw an error; how you handle it is up to you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

When using surrogate keys, sequences are the recommended way in Oracle, and auto increment column in MySQL.

As for time, in oracle you need two steps, converting current time to single number, unix timestamp, and then converting the number to base 36.

[Getting timestamp](https://shafiqissani.wordpress.com/2010/09/30/how-to-get-the-current-epoch-time-unix-timestamp/)

```
SELECT (SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01-01-1970 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 60 * 60 FROM DUAL
```

Creating  function for [base conversion](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-jul/o46asktom-085866.html) (see code listing 3).

```
create or replace function to_base( p_dec in number, p_base in number )
return varchar2
is
    l_str   varchar2(255) default NULL;
    l_num   number  default p_dec;
    l_hex   varchar2(50) default '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
begin
    if ( trunc(p_dec) <> p_dec OR p_dec < 0 ) then
        raise PROGRAM_ERROR;
    end if;
    loop
        l_str := substr( l_hex, mod(l_num,p_base)+1, 1 ) || l_str;
        l_num := trunc( l_num/p_base );
        exit when ( l_num = 0 );
    end loop;
    return l_str;
end to_base;
/
```

Then the query can look like this

```
SELECT to_base((SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01-01-1970 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 60 * 60, 36) FROM DUAL
```

We can further simplify the last query with a functon

```
create or replace function get_timestamp_base36 return varchar2 is
begin
    return to_base((SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01-01-1970 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 60 * 60, 36);
end get_timestamp_base36;
```